# Savitch's theorem and time relation

Tags: time-complexity

We know that $NTIME(t(n)) \subseteq DSPACE(t(n))$ and we know - by Savitch's theorem - that $NSPACE(s(n)) \subseteq DSPACE(s^2(n))$.

By the space/time relation $(s(n) \leq t(n))$ I know that $NTIME(t(n)) \subseteq NSPACE(t(n))$, then by Savitch's theorem $NSPACE(t(n)) \subseteq DSPACE(t^2(n))$ and not $DSPACE(t(n))$, as stated above.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you left out [big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)s around those bounds.

In any case, $\; \{0\} \subseteq \{\hspace{-0.02 in}0,\hspace{-0.05 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\} \;$ *and* $\; \{0\} \subseteq \{\hspace{-0.02 in}0,\hspace{-0.05 in}1,\hspace{-0.04 in}2\hspace{-0.02 in}\}$ , $\;$ even though $\: \{\hspace{-0.02 in}0,\hspace{-0.05 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\} \neq \{\hspace{-0.02 in}0,\hspace{-0.05 in}1,\hspace{-0.04 in}2\hspace{-0.02 in}\}$ .

Comment: So Savitch's theorem gives just a bigger upper bound?

Comment: Well, _the combination you used_ just gives a bigger upper bound. ​ ​

Comment: But I'm not adding anything to Savitch's theorem, I'm starting from $NSPACE(t(n))$ and getting $DSPACE(t^2(n))$. Then why Savitch did it this way, if we already know $NSPACE(t(n)) = DSPACE(t(n))$ due to the fact we can reuse space?

Comment: How do "we already know" ​ NSPACE(t(n)) $\subseteq$ DSPACE(t(n)) ​ "due to the fact we can reuse space?" ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Because $NTIME(t(n)) \subseteq NSPACE(t(n)) \subseteq DSPACE(t(n))$, the first assertion is due to the fact $t(n) \leq s(n)$ and $NTIME(t(n)) \subseteq DSPACE(t(n))$ is due to the fact that when you simulate a NTM you need at most O(t(n)) space.

Comment: So, you have that the left is a subset of the middle and the left is a subset of the right. ​ How do you get that the middle is a subset of the right? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Oh, here is the problem, I can't apply transitivity.

Comment: I think your example would be more appropriate if you say something like: $\{0\} \subseteq \{0,1\} \land \{0\} \subseteq \{0,3\}$, even though $\{0,1\} \not\subset \{0,3\}$. Thank you for your help.